# Custom binary search in vector

Tags: c++, search, vector, binary-search

Suppose I have a `vector<int> myVec`. Let there be `n` elements in it. I know that these elements are in sorted order(ascending) and also that they are unique. Let `n = 10` and `myVec` be {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}. I'm given `l` and `r` such that `0<=l<=r<=n-1`. Now i want to search an element `val` in the **subvector** that is defined by the bounds `l` and `r`such that

1. if `val` is found return `val`
2. if `val` is not found then return (if possible) a value in the **subvector** which is just smaller than `val`.
3. Return false(or -1 maybe) if either of the above is not possible.

In the above case if if `l = 3` and `r = 5`. The subvector is {8, 10, 12}. If `val = 8` return 8. If `val = 7` return false (or -1). If `val = 9` return 8.

How do I implement this. **I want order comparable to binary search.** Also, is it possible to use `std::binary_search()`  present under `algorithm` header file.

Comment: If you want to do a binary search an algorithm named `binary_search` does sound promising. Why didn't you try it?

Comment: @ZanLynx it is not plain binary search. There are other conditions as well.

Comment: I don't see how the other conditions make a difference. Please explain.

Comment: @ZanLynx See what happens when val = 9. It returns the element in subvector which is just smaller than 9 i.e. 8.

Comment: Do you absolutely need a binary search? How about using `std::lower_bound` instead?

Comment: @TartanLlama I cannot apply lower_bound to subvector until i copy its elements in a new vector.  If you think it can be done without having any overheads tell me how.

Comment: I wrote an answer but then realized you probably meant in condition (2) that the value should be the biggest value in the subvector which is still smaller than val... You can implement the binary search yourself and when your the range is minimized to an empty set (in case no element exists) just look one step to the current pivot left - if it's still in the subvector return it, otherwise return false.

Answer (score 0):

Using traditional binary search with minor modification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int search(const std::vector<int> &vec, int l, int r, int val)
{
        int pivot, xl = l, xr = r, mid;

        do {
                /* Not exact match, check if the closest lower match is in the 
                 * subvector. */
                if (xl > xr) {
                        return xr >= l ? vec[xr]: -1;
                }

                mid = (xl + xr) / 2;
                pivot = vec[mid];
                if (val < pivot) {
                        xr = mid - 1;
                } else if (val > pivot) {
                        xl = mid + 1;
                } else if (val == pivot) {
                        return val;
                }
        } while (true);
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> myVec(10);
        myVec[0] = 2;
        myVec[1] = 4;
        myVec[2] = 6;
        myVec[3] = 8;
        myVec[4] = 10;
        myVec[5] = 12;
        myVec[6] = 14;
        myVec[7] = 16;
        myVec[8] = 18;
        myVec[9] = 20;

        int l = 3, r = 5;

        std::cout << "search(3, 5, 8) = " << search(myVec, 3, 5, 8) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "search(3, 5, 7) = " << search(myVec, 3, 5, 7) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "search(3, 5, 9) = " << search(myVec, 3, 5, 9) << std::endl;

        return 0;
}

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
int search(int l, int r, int value) {
  if (l > vec.Size() || r > vec.Size() || l > r) return -1;
  for (int i = r; i >= l; --i) {
    int v = vector[i];
    if (v <= value) return v;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

or does it need to be binary?

```
int BinarySearch(int l, int r, int value) {
  return PrivateBinarySearch(l, r, (l+r)/2, value);
}

int PrivateBinarySearch(int l, int r, int index, int value) {
  if (vector[index] == value) return value;
  else if (vector[index] > value) {
    if (index == l) return -1;
    else if (index == r) return -1;
    else return PrivateBinarySearch(l, index, (index-1+l)/2, value);
  }
  else { // vector[index] < value
    if (index == l) return vector[index];
    else if (index == r) return vector[index];
    else return PrivateBinarySearch(index, r, (index+1+r)/2, value);
  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you and is pretty extensible and flexible:

```
template<typename T>
typename vector<T>::const_iterator 
find_or_under (typename vector<T>::const_iterator start, typename vector<T>::const_iterator end, 
                const T& val)
{
    auto el = std::lower_bound(start, end, val);

    //if not found, propagate
    if (el == end)
        return el;

    //if it's equal, just return the iterator
    if ((*el) == val)
        return el;

    //if there is no value of an equal or smaller size, return the end
    if (el == start)
        return end;

    //otherwise, return the previous element
    return el-1;
}

//Functor representing the search
struct CustomSearch
{
    //Create a searcher from a subrange
    CustomSearch (const vector<int> &v, size_t l, size_t r)
    {
        start = std::lower_bound(std::begin(v), std::end(v), l);
        end = find_or_under(start, std::end(v), r) + 1;
    }

    //Calling the searcher
    //Returns this->end on not found
    auto operator() (int val)
    {
        return find_or_under(start, end, val);
    }

    vector<int>::const_iterator start;
    vector<int>::const_iterator end;
};

int main() {
    vector<int> v =  {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
    CustomSearch searcher {v, 3, 8};
    cout << *searcher(6);
}
```